# Gradient quantization in data-parallel SGD with a custom quantizer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, quantization

I would like to perform data-parallel SGD training with my own gradient quantization (in order to reduce the communication). Each worker node sends the encoded (compressed) gradient to the master node. The master node decodes the compressed gradient and updates the parameters. I will use my own encoding (quantization) and decoding functions.

I was wondering under which deep learning framework it is relatively easier to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow has a built in distributed (parameter server) approach. [Tensor flow Distributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)

Horovod from uber engg is exclusively dedicated to this problem. [Horovod overview](https://github.com/uber/horovod)[Horovod github](https://github.com/uber/horovod). 
I personally prefer the Horovod approach as it scales across tensorflow & pytorch. And realistically many teams use diff tookits for diff problems today. So if you are investing the time make it easy to port across toolkits.